# Swift AddressBook - copy all people in source with sort ordering issue

Tags: sorting, swift, addressbook

here is the issue I'm getting. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
var addressBook: ABAddressBookRef = {
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    return ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil,
    &error).takeRetainedValue() as ABAddressBookRef
}()    

var source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook)!

var allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source: source, sortOrdering: kABPersonSortByFirstName)
```

Error message: Cannot convert the expression's type '(ABAddressBookRef, source: @lvalue Unmanaged, sortOrdering: Int)' to type '$T4'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors: `ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource()` returns
`Unmanaged<ABRecord>!`, so you have to call `takeRetainedValue()`
on the returned value.

And the last argument to `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering()` must
be converted to the expected type `ABPersonSortOrdering`:

```
var source: ABRecord = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook).takeRetainedValue()

var allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook,
    source, ABPersonSortOrdering(kABPersonSortByFirstName))
```

Comment: Thanks!! One more issue... how do I convert an unmanaged<CFArray> to a CFArray or even better, an NSArray?

Comment: because allPeople is currently of type unmanaged<CFArray> which I cant iterate through with a loop

Comment: @user3471847: Perhaps `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(...).takeRetainedValue() as [ABRecord]`   ?

Comment: @user3471847: Which Xcode version are you using? It compiles in my Xcode 6.2.

Comment: 6.1 - will update now. Thanks  for the help, much appreciated

Comment: @MartinR - Good answer, but shouldn't you really use optional chaining (e.g. `?.takeRetainedValue()`, combined with optional binding, to gracefully handle `nil` values?

Comment: @Rob: I am not 100% sure, but the ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource() documentation does *not* state that it can return NULL/nil, therefore I assumed that it always succeeds. ABAddressBookGetSourceWithRecordID(), for example, *can* return NULL. I assume that the address book functions haven't yet been audited for optional conformance, they all return implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Comment: "ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource" not getting all Contact...could any one assist me here?